# What is the secret of the arduino `yield()`function?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide

The Arduino docs explain `yield()` at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Scheduler with regards to the Due. Apparently it is part of the Scheduler library:

```
#include <Scheduler.h>
```

However, I can call `yield()` on my Nano or ESP8266 without including the Scheduler lib -- but only in my main program, not inside include files. Also, the include does not work on my non-Dues.

What's the secret that I'm missing about `yield()` or- what does `yield()` do on Arduino platforms other than Due?

Comment: Is another header that you are including in your main file including `Scheduler.h`?

Comment: No. You can have a skeleton sketch that just calls yield() and it will compile. There must be some hidden magic. If the downvote is yours kindly let me know what I should have researched beyond googling up and down the universe....

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> However, I can call yield() on my Nano or ESP8266 without including
>   the Scheduler lib

The `yield()` function is also implemented inside the **ESP8266** libraries:

> **Yielding**
>
> This is one of the most critical differences between the ESP8266 and a
>   more classical Arduino microcontroller. The ESP8266 runs a lot of
>   utility functions in the background – keeping WiFi connected, managing
>   the TCP/IP stack, and performing other duties. Blocking these
>   functions from running can cause the ESP8266 to crash and reset
>   itself. To avoid these mysterious resets, avoid long, blocking loops
>   in your sketch.
>
> **The amazing creators of the ESP8266 Arduino libraries also implemented
>   a yield() function**, which calls on the background functions to allow
>   them to do their things.

That's why you can call `yield()` from within your main program where the ESP8266 header is included.

See [ESP8266 Thing Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/using-the-arduino-addon).

**Update**:

`yield()` is defined in Arduino.h as:

```
void yield(void);
```

`yield()` is also declared in `hooks.h` as follows:

```
/**
 * Empty yield() hook.
 *
 * This function is intended to be used by library writers to build
 * libraries or sketches that supports cooperative threads.
 *
 * Its defined as a weak symbol and it can be redefined to implement a
 * real cooperative scheduler.
 */
static void __empty() {
    // Empty
}
void yield(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("__empty")));
```

So, on the `Nano`, it probably does nothing (unless you have other libraries `#included`).

Comment: Thank you- why would this work when compiling for Nano though? Is yield an empty placeholder on other non-Due platforms?

Comment: @andig - Do you have other libraries included on the Nano?

Comment: Well, it is at least defined in Arduino.h like this: `void yield(void);`. I'll look it up further, and come back to you.

Comment: While yielding is great to allow handle network stuff in the background it also introduces a problem that many people are not aware of: 
You have two tasks running on your ESP8266 - and you may corrupt your data if you are not careful enough.

I created a blog post about this issue, see https://euphi.github.io/2018/03/31/ArduinoESP8266-multipleTasks.html .

Comment: Does it mean that `delay` is not real on  ESP?

Answer (score 5):

yield is a "weak" function from Arduino core for AVR. I see one call for it inside wiring.c.

```
void delay(unsigned long ms)
{
    uint32_t start = micros();

    while (ms > 0) {
        yield();
        while ( ms > 0 && (micros() - start) >= 1000) {
            ms--;
            start += 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

This means that the yield() function will be executed during the loop of delay function. Thus, yield would be used for some background processing while the delay ends or for doing a function with timeout feature.

Note: yield must be defined in application/sketch

UPDATE: The question made me excited to make a little [post about yield and other hidden features from arduino core](https://atadiat.com/en/micros/e-yield-function-printable-class-mapping-arrays-useful-arduino-core/).

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/search?q=yield+&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93