# What is the effect of adding too many yield() in Arduino ESP8266?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Adding yield() will reduce random resets in ESP8266. What if the code has too many yield()? What is the side effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the secret of the arduino \`yield()\`function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497758/what-is-the-secret-of-the-arduino-yieldfunction)

Comment: Calling `yield()` is a code smell IMO that simply makes up for lack of proper event handling.

Comment: I have a callback function which is processor-intensive. I have no choice but to use yield(). yield() can be a life-saver.

Comment: Yes, it _can_ be but since it's so readily available it doesn't really force you to think twice about running processor-intensive operations and thereby not feeding the watch dog.

Comment: will using yield() cause a slowdown in the performance?

Comment: Yes, but it may not be noticeable, depends on your code. Whenever you `yield` you give the processor a chance to execute background tasks rather than your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the yield command just gives the esp the opportunity to handle internal stuff. It´s way better than using waits - delay() and I couldn't find a noticeable performance impact.